# Magic Launcher error logging in

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

Hello. When I log into Minecraft it says that there is an "error connecting to servers". When I see the error log, it says:

```
MagicLauncher 1.0.0
java.home: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7
java.runtime.name: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
java.runtime.version: 1.7.0_09-b05
os.name: Windows 7
os.version: 6.1
os.arch: amd64
sun.arch.data.model: 64
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at magic.launcher.ak.a(Unknown Source)
    at magic.launcher.z.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Error loading: .http://www.minecraftforum.net/rss/writ/1-news/: Connection reset
Error loading: .http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=from%3Ajeb_: Connection reset
Error loading: .http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=from%3ADinnerbone: Connection reset
Error checking for new version: Connection reset
Error loading: .http://reddit.com/r/minecraft.rss: Connection reset
Error loading: .http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=from%3Anotch: Connection reset
Error loading: .http://notch.tumblr.com/rss: Connection reset
```

Comment: You don't appear to be connected to the internet. Check your firewall

Comment: write that as answer so we can vote you

Comment: @iMAGEbox That was a guess, and a request that the asker gathers more information. It's not an answer. (It's kind of silly hearing you try to repeat my advice to you to an administrator who knows what they're doing. Just take care of your own comments and answers, please.)

Answer (score 1):

Connection reset errors generally means that a firewall is blocking Magic Launcher from connecting to the internet.  Either disable your firewall, or allow Magic Launcher through.

Answer (score -2):

Just delete minecraft and then reinstall this happened to me I did this and it worked just fine